# Is it possible to have a private class?

Tags: java

Is it possible to have a private class?

Comment: More information on the specific use case would be helpful for detailed answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you start with Java - on the first degrees on your learning curve you will eventually not need any private classes. They make sense for inner classes (a class within a class) when this inner class is not usable/useful outside the parent class.

But for now: just keep in mind, that private is not forbidden in general for classes but don't use this modifier.

Or - if you use eclipse/netbeans: just create a class, change the modifier from public to private and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes. They're useful for inner classes.